# Is there any way to debug bootloaders/BIOS of a virtual machine on Hyper-V (as can be done on QEMU with GDB)?

Tags: debugging, virtual-machine, bootloader, hyper-v

QEMU has a `-gdb` option that enables the use of GDB (or any debugger that understands GDB's remote protocol) to step through bootloaders and even the BIOS/UEFI firmware of a virtual machine. Does Hyper-V (or any related MS product) have an equivalent to this? Is there any way whatsoever that a bootloader in a Hyper-V VM could be stepped through with a debugger (like WinDbg/KD)?

If not, are there any technical reasons for this limitation, or is it simply not a feature that Microsoft chose to implement?